# DIsplay Array in a specific format

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array say arr1 = ["Review", "Journal Article"]
I need to display it in a specific format like 
arr2 = ["Review , Journal Article"]

Input :

```
arr1 = ["Review", "Journal Article"]
```

Expected Result:

```
arr2 = ["Review , Journal Article"]
```

Comment: display where? Are you trying to concat all the elements of an array?

Comment: just I need to get the array in that expected format in console

Comment: Can you please elaborate? where will you be displaying the array? And what's the programming language?

Comment: do you want a single element after all concat in a resultant array object ?

Comment: Oh... you want that format in console output... If so, try console.log(arr1.join(" , "))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```js
const arr1 = ["Review", "Journal Article"];
const arr2 = [arr1.join(' , ')];

console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: The other guy was 6 seconds quicker than you, and got the exact same code snippet (except const -> var) :D

Comment: @d0n.key For `array` better use `const`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and affect the returned value into an array

```js
var arr1 = ["Review", "Journal Article"]
var arr2 = [arr1.join(' , ')];
    
console.log(arr2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the joined elements as new element in an array.

```js
var array = ["Review", "Journal Article"],
    result = [array.join(' , ')];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case with an array you can achieve what you want like this:

```
var output = ["Review", "Journal Article"].map(x => '"' + x + '"');
output[0] = "[" + output[0].substring(1);
output[output.length - 1] = output[output.length - 1].substring(0, output[output.length - 1].length - 1) + "]";
var str = "arr2 = " + output.join(", ");
```